# error on dependency injection in interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have three files app.js, common.services.js and tokenContainer.js . When i tried to inject tokenContainer dependency to interceptor of app.js, I get an error :

**Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tokenContainerProvider <- tokenContainer <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile**

common.service.js file

```
(function () {
        "use strict";

        angular
            .module("common.services",
                        ["ngResource"])
            .constant("appSettings",
            {
                serverPath: "http://localhost:6359"
            });
    }());
```

tokenContainer.js file :

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("tokenContainer",
                  [tokenContainer])

    function tokenContainer() {

        var container = {
            token: ""
        };

        var setToken = function (token) {
            container.token = token;
        };

        var getToken = function () {

        };

        return {
            getToken: getToken
        };
    };

})();
```

app.js file :

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("productManagement",
                            ["ngRoute", "common.services"]);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when("/products", {
                templateUrl: "app/products/productListView.html",
                controller: "ProductListCtrl as vm"
            })
            .when("/products/create", {
                templateUrl: "app/products/productCreateView.html",
                controller: "ProductCreateCtrl as vm"
            })
            .when("/login", {
                templateUrl: "app/login/login.html",
                controller: "loginController as vm"
            })
           .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/products" });

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function (appSettings, tokenContainer) {
            return {
                'request': function (config) {
                    // ToDo :             
                    return config;
                }

            };
        });

    });

}());
```

Comment: In what order are you including the scripts?

Comment: yes..!!! actually i forgot to include the reference of tokenContainer.js file. Than you for pointing out :)